# C# Engine Object replacement for web service call

Tags: c#, web-services, trim

I am currently working on an MVC site that will hopefully consume an old `.asmx` Web Service. The documentation for the Web Service provides the following example:

```
// Construct a request object
TrimRequest request = new TrimRequest();

// Construct a RecordStringSearchClause, with type
// TitleWord, and argument "reef"
RecordStringSearchClause clause = new RecordStringSearchClause();
clause.Type = RecordStringSearchClauseType.TitleWord;
clause.Arg = "reef";

// Construct a record search, and put our search clause in it
WorkerPortalTest.TRIMWS.RecordSearch search = new WorkerPortalTest.TRIMWS.RecordSearch();
search.Items = new RecordClause[] { clause };

// If we had more than one clause, it would look like:
// search.Items = new RecordClause[] { clause1, clause2, clause3 }
// Put our search operation into our TrimRequest
request.Items = new Operation[] { search };

// Send it off. Whatever comes back will be in response
Engine engine = new Engine();
engine.Credentials = newSystem.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
TrimResponse response = engine.Execute(request);
```

As a fairly new C# programmer I understand all of it apart from the last three lines. I have never seen or used the `Engine object` and Visual Studio does not know of it either.. I looked through MSDN and found [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.engine(v=vs.121).aspx) but it said it was deprecated.

I am just looking for some pointers in the right direction to call the Web Service and receive back the desired result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Engine is an example of the webservice class. It calls a method in Engine class known as "Execute"..

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I did figure that much out, however the `Engine` class no longer exists. What class can I use in its place with .Net 4?